# Example of non-commutative association scheme

Tags: abstract-algebra, association-schemes

I need an example of non-commutative association scheme of ordered 6. I tried to use the example in the book Handbook of Combinatorial Designs, Second Edition
by Charles J. Colbourn‏،Jeffrey H. Dini but I could not reach the answer.

I took $G=\mathbb{Z_{6}}$ acts transitively on itself by $g\oplus x$ for all g and x in $\mathbb{Z_6}$. $G$ acts naturally on the set$ \mathbb{Z_6} \times \mathbb{Z_6}$ by $g(x_1,x_2)=(g\oplus x_1,g\oplus x_2)$ for all $g ,x_1$ , and $x_2$ in $\mathbb{Z_6}$. Letting $R_i=O((x,y))$ for all (x,y) in $\mathbb{ Z_6} \times \mathbb{Z_6}$ Where the O((x,y))is the orbit set of (x,y). I got 6 relations which make a commutative assocation scheme.

Comment: How do you "try to use an example" but "not reach an answer."?

Answer (score 0):

Everything I've found suggests that the notion of an association scheme is a generalization of a group.

That being the case, then the group of symmetries of an equilateral  triangle is an example.

Comment: Does that mean a dihedral group?

Comment: @user275240 yes, the symmetries of a regular polygon are also called dihedral groups

Comment: Could I ask you Which group can be work on this example That makes a non-commutative association scheme : Let a group $G$ act transitively on a finite set $X$. Then G acts naturally on the
set $X ×X$ by $(x, y)g = (xg, yg)$. Under this action, the set $R_0 = \{(x, x) : x \in X\}$ is an orbit. Let $X ×X$ be decomposed into the $d+1$
orbits $R_0,R_1, . . . ,R_d$. This set of orbits forms a d-class association scheme.

Comment: @user275240 I'm not familiar enough with the subject matter to say with certainty which groups $G$ will work in that construction. But if having order 6 matters, then there are only two abelian groups of order 6 and one non-abelian one, so that may limit your possibilities.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: @user275240 Indeed, the method you are using creates a non-commutative association scheme if and only if the group you use is nonabelian (so take the dihedral group).

Comment: @MorganRodgers I used the symmetric group $S_3$ but didn't work.

Comment: @user275240 For future reference, comments that are just "I tried but it didn't work." are totally useless. You really ought to mention what went wrong. Do you mean it created an association scheme that is commutative? Do you mean that you couldn't figure out some step? What?

Answer (score 0):

Here are all association schemes of order 6:
http://math.shinshu-u.ac.jp/~hanaki/as/data/as06
Clearly a symmetric association scheme is also commutative.
So you have to check just No.4 and 6 in the catalogue to figure out which one is non-commutative.